# Picking a tile in an Iso Engine

Tags: isometric, picking

I have developed an iso engine for a farm game. In general it works fine, but the problem is that it is not always accurate when pressing the tiles, so the tile I wanted to select is not the one picked. Anybody has some ideas how to improve this?

Comment: You should at least provide some code that shows what you're currently doing so that people can tell you how to improve on it.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a transform matrix. Check out this tutorial:
http://www.alcove-games.com/isometric_tile_picking.php

Comment: Could you provide a few paragraphs on what a transform matrix is? Link-only answers are highly discouraged on the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: ok basically what we're trying to do is creating a transform matrix that will match the isometric world. So then, when looking up for coordinates of your isometric tiles, all you have to do is vector v = inv(transformMatrix) * vector u. Your game camera is in fact a transform matrix. It just is very basic (identity matrix scaled by some factor). The transform matrix for an iso world is a bit trickier (rotation by 45 degree, scaling, translation) but there is nothing that is really complicated. Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh, I have no interest in this post, I was reviewing. I meant for you to add that into your post--it helps prevent link rot.

Answer (score 0):

In [this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/14274/finding-out-which-tile-a-mouse-click-landed-in/14291#14291) the ratio between the projected diagonal of a square laying on the ground are 70:30. You can generalize with ease for the particular perspective you are using.