# Isometric tiles drawing and picking - JAVA

Tags: java, tiles, isometric, picking, swing

I'm trying to draw isometric tiles in Java and implement a tile picking system using the mouse cursor. I draw the tiles using math formulas I found and adapted to my tile textures which you can find below. Tiles are 64x64px but flat tiles are only 32px height even if I draw them using the 64x64 sprite.

```
public int[] toIso(int x, int y){

    int i = (x - y) * tileWidthHalf;
    int j = (x + y) * tileHeightQuarter;

    i+=xOffset;
    j+=yOffset;

    return new int[]{i,j};
}

public int[] toGrid(int x, int y){

    x-=xOffset;
    y-=yOffset;

    int i = (x/tileWidthHalf + y/tileHeightQuarter)/2;
    int j = (y/tileHeightQuarter - x/tileWidthHalf)/2;

    return new int[]{i,j};
}
```

[image: Tile sheet]

The map is a simple 2d array where my tiles are represented by their id.

[image: Tile picking]

Here is a video showing what is actually happening: [youtu.be/baCVIfJz2Wo](http://youtu.be/baCVIfJz2Wo)

---

Comment: Does this help? https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/14274/finding-out-which-tile-a-mouse-click-landed-in

Comment: It seems not to work in my case. Thanks though.

Comment: I don't fully understand what the problem is. Could you improve the question to highlight what you get and what you expect instead?

Comment: Well, I'm trying to detect which tile is under my mouse when hovering the grid and render it with a different texture for the moment. The problem is, the tile selection isn't accurate at all, as you can see in the video I provided.

Comment: The `toGrid` and `toIso` functions are clearly not reversible. If they are both accurate, you should be able to call `toIso` on a set of coordinates; and then call `toGrid` on that result and end up with essentially the same coordinates you started with (working with integers may mean you are off by a pixel or so however).

Write yourself a quick unit test which dumps the coordinates into the console and see what results you get. If they vary wildly, then your calculations are likely wrong.

Comment: In fact you're right. This method only works one way. But the problem is then, how to convert my screen coordinates to map coordinates? Thanks for your helpful comment. @JasonH

Comment: There's already a question asking and answering that very question here: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/12362/isometric-rendering-and-picking?rq=1

Comment: I saw it but this solution doesn't work with my tiles.

Comment: Could you clarify what is wrong with your tiles when using that method? If it's due to your tiles being 64x64; you can just apply an offset to the calculation to set the origin to where you want it to be.

Comment: It seems like applying an offset doesn't solve the problem. I actually really don't understand what is happening. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: which values you use for tileWidthHalf and tileHeightQuarter. I would bet modfiying these values would help

Comment: My tiles are actually 64px width and 64px height, so it makes tileWidthHalf=32 and tileHeightQuarter=16. I'll try to change my spriteSheet. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just wanted to say that I finally solved it. It was just a conversion to int issue. These are the final methods that I use. Hope it will help people who were trying to work with isometric tiles. Thank you !

```
public static int[] toIso(int x, int y){

    int i = (x - y) * TILE_WIDTH_HALF;
    int j = (x + y) * TILE_HEIGHT_QUARTER;

    i += xOffset-TILE_WIDTH_HALF;
    j+=yOffset;

    return new int[]{i,j};
}

public static int[] toGrid(double i, double j){

    i-=xOffset;
    j-=yOffset;

    double tx = Math.ceil(((i / TILE_WIDTH_HALF) + (j / TILE_HEIGHT_QUARTER))/2);
    double ty = Math.ceil(((j / TILE_HEIGHT_QUARTER) - (i / TILE_WIDTH_HALF))/2);

    int x = (int) Math.ceil(tx)-1;
    int y = (int) Math.ceil(ty)-1;

    return new int[]{x, y};
}
```