# Isometric Rendering and Picking

Tags: rendering, tiles, isometric, mouse, picking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Isometric rendering and picking?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/12362/isometric-rendering-and-picking)

I've been looking for a formula to plot (world->screen) and mouse pick (world->screen) isometric tiles in a non-diamond-shaped world. What's the usual/correct way to do this?

Comment: OK, so it's not diamond shaped. Then what is it? I guess since your question is next to identical to [this one](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/12362/isometric-rendering-and-picking?rq=1), you have seen it? I imagine something could be adapted from that.

Comment: Well, the world is isometric, but you don't see the shape of the map, the map is drawn to cover ALL the screen,but still using isometric picking (games like Theme Hospital or Pox Nora). The world is a square-shaped, and not a diamond-shaped.

And I copied that question because I was not sure if I could explain the question with my poor english... Sorry about that.

Comment: @Byte56 Vote to close.  This is a copy and paste duplicate.

Comment: @bobobobo Nearly, it's asking about non-diamond-shaped, instead of diamond-shaped. But yeah, since OP is *actually* asking about the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

I think you may be confusing some terms. Theme Hospital *is* diamond shaped [from what](http://img.gamespot.com/gamespot/images/screenshots/4/198994/themhosp_screen004.jpg) I can tell. That's the shape of the tiles, not the entire world. You can shape the entire would however you like. The shape of the world would be the same as the shape of the tiles if the world was square (meaning equal width and height), but you don't need to make it that way.

You can use the algorithms described for [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/12362/isometric-rendering-and-picking?rq=1). It's just an artistic style that will make it look like Theme hospital or Poxnora.