# Isometric Tile Selection with rectangular bounding boxes

Tags: isometric, coordinates

I am having problems trying to determine which tile I have selected with the mouse.

Currently it selects two tiles, rather than one. Producing the following results:

[image]

My tiles height, is half their width, and all tiles have the same dimensions.

The tiles are rectangles and their Cartesian position has been translated to a relative isometric position.

Because I am checking the mouse position with the sprites bounds, it will select two tiles, as demonstrated in the image below:

[image]

I suppose my question is, how to I determine that my mouse x/y is within the 'diamond' of the rectangle?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Isometric rendering and picking?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/12362/isometric-rendering-and-picking)

Comment: What type of isometric world do you have? Diamond or rectangular?

Answer (score 1):

This is how the original Civ 1 does it:

It separates the world into rectangles as you do, each rectangle's width and height is the same as the maximum width and height of a tile.

When you click on the screen, it gets the relative position if the mouse from the current rectangle's top-left corner and gets the color from the following image with thise relative coordinates.

[image: Picking]

Based on the cootrdinate, it can determine the currently picked tile.

**How you should do it**

An isometric tile is a square rotated 45 degrees and scaled vertically to ½.

By reversing this you can transform the mouse's position to a grid. If you divide these coordinates with the height of the tile then you get the currently picked tile.

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the blind, but I can see two potential solutions:

**Per-pixel collision detection:** This is probably too much for the job, but using per-pixel collision detection would solve the issue, as only one tile would have opaque pixel under the cursor at a time.

**Distance:** When multiple tiles could be selected, calculate the absolute distance ( sqrt((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2) ) between the cursor and the centre of the tile. The tile under the cursor will be the one that's the closest.

Comment: The distance-based metric suggested here will effectively select a cell from the [Voronoi diagram](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) of the points. Unfortunately, for an isometric map, the Voronoi diagram of the tile centers is a hexagonal grid — not the grid of rhombuses you actually want to select within, causing mismatches in the selected tile. You can fix this by scaling the y axis before computing the distance.