# Isometric tiles math for 4:3 ratio (64 x 48 pixels)

Tags: isometric

I've read and tested the code from this article, http://clintbellanger.net/articles/isometric_math/, and also from this [Isometric rendering and picking?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/12362/isometric-rendering-and-picking) and I can get the math and tile picking to work properly for a 2:1 isometric base tiles. However I haven't come across any article on tile picking math that involves a 4:3 ratio isometric base tiles. Can I just use the same math for the 4:3 ratio isometric or should I change it to make it work? If so, can anyone point me in the right direction of what is the right tile picking math for a 4:3 ratio isometric base tiles?

Thank you.